# insert automatico en tabla B cuando se inserte un registro en la tabla A si el campo numero existe e la tabla c

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger

Buenas tardes amigos estaria tendiendo la siguiente estructura

Tabla A
id
patente
numero
fecha

Tabla B
id
patente
salida
numero

Tabla C
id
nombre
patente

Desearia saber como hago para hacer un insert automatico de la tabla B, cuando se inserta un registro en la tabla A siempre y cuando el campo patente exista en la tabla C, soy nueva con procedimientos almacenados y no estaría sabiendo como hacer si alguien me puede orientar

Comment: Considera que la pregunta puede quedar cerrada pues no se ajusta a [ask] y carece de un [mcve]

Comment: Al pedir orientaciones y no adjuntar un [repro], haces que tu pregunta sea muy amplia y esté basada en opiniones, por lo tanto podría terminar [cerrada](/help/closed-questions). No ignores las recomendaciones que te han dado: lee [ask] y edita tu pregunta.

Comment: No sabemos el tipo de dato de las columnas, los datos que puede haber en ellas ni las condiciones para insertar. Por favor, edita tu pregunta como te indican y añade la descripción de las tablas (los `CREATE TABLE`, por ejemplo), algún par de datos de prueba y lo que debería quedar en la tabla B. Añáde también lo que no te ha funcionado en este par de días que has probado, que así será muy fácil guiarte y ayudar. Ayúdanos a ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu problema puede ser resuelto con un trigger
Este contiene x instrucciones y es llamado cuando se realiza un update, create o delete en la tabla que escojamos.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Nombre_trigger
ON Tabla A
AFTER INSERT
    AS
    IF EXISTS(select * from Tabla C where patente == INSERTED.patente )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Tabla B 
            (patente, salida, numero)
            VALUES (INSERTED.patente, INSERTED.salida, INSERTED.numero)
        END
```

ya solo agrégale la condición de que exista en Tabla C para que se inserte en Tabla B

La tabla inserted de donde tomara los datos para insertarlos en la Tabla B es una tabla temporal que contiene los valores que se insertan (INSERTED), actualizan(DELETED + INSERTED) o eliminan (DELETED).

Actualizar consta de 2 tablas dado que en el proceso de actualizar se tiene que eliminar el registro existente para posteriormente insertar el dato actualizado.

En cuanto a la palabra "AFTER" indica en que momento se ejecutara el trigger, siendo los mas comunes "AFTER" y "BEFORE".

Comment: Gracias por toda la ayuda la estoy analizando porque no se mucho de base de datos

Comment: Pese a que tu respuesta podría ser útil para el OP (autor de la pregunta), considera no responder a preguntas que necesiten más detalles o aclaración. Lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_.

Comment: esta comunidad se supone que es para ayudarnos entre todos hice un esquema del escenario que tengo y especifique que no se hacer un trigger y pedi orientacion y esta persona no dudo en ayudarme a guiarme a veces hay que ponerse en el lugar del otro que está solo batallando puede llevar días tratando de resolver un tema antes de llegar aqui

Comment: @IngDePáez es muchísimo más fácil ayudar de forma efectiva al que _está batallando_ si los demás pueden leer una pregunta con info suficiente para no tener que adivinar o hacer N ejemplos hasta que alguno se ajuste a lo que busca quien pregunta. Las recomendaciones sobre el formato de la pregunta son para poder ayudar, no para entorpecer.